# How do I call or select tables from two different database using PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql

Recently I used to work with postgresql function, but I got some problem with processing table from other database. Is it possible to do that (select table from other database) using PostgreSQL? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: You need to use a foreign data wrapper: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).

> dblink executes a query (usually a SELECT, but it can be any SQL
>   statement that returns rows) in a remote database.

The syntax is: `dblink(text connstr, text sql [, bool fail_on_error]) returns setof record`

Where

> **connstr** - libpq-style connection info string, for example hostaddr=127.0.0.1
>   port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypasswd. Alternatively, the name of a foreign server.
>
> **sql** - The SQL query that you wish to execute in the remote database, for example select * from foo.

Comment: Using a foreign data wrapper is the preferred way nowadays.